# Remove duplicates from an object array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an object array that looks like this:

```
Array
(
[0] =>Object
        (
            [ClassScheduleID] => 2263
            [Name] => Workout 1
            [Location] => Object
            (
                [BusinessID] => 1
            )
)
[1] =>Object
        (
            [ClassScheduleID] => 2263
            [Name] => Workout 1
            [Location] => Object
            (
                [BusinessID] => 13
            )
)
[2] =>Object
        (
            [ClassScheduleID] => 2264
            [Name] => Workout 2
            [Location] => Object
            (
                [BusinessID] => 22
            )
)
```

I am looking to identify that the ClassScheduleID of 2263 is a duplicate, and remove the duplicate entry's entire object from the array. So that I get:

```
Array
    (
    [0] =>Object
            (
                [ClassScheduleID] => 2263
                [Name] => Workout 1
                [Location] => Object
                (
                    [BusinessID] => 1
                )
    )

    [1] =>Object
            (
                [ClassScheduleID] => 2264
                [Name] => Workout 2
                [Location] => Object
                (
                    [BusinessID] => 22
                )
    )
```

I tried the solution proposed here

[How to remove duplicate values from a multi-dimensional array in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307674/how-to-remove-duplicate-values-from-a-multi-dimensional-array-in-php)

but the count() remained the same

Comment: Why don't you use the class schedule id as the key? That way you can't have duplicates.

Comment: The solution you tried is for arrays that are identical.  Yours are not, the `BusinessID` is different.

Comment: I am working with a defaulted output. If I want to change the key, then I need to rearrange the array myself.  How would I do that?

Comment: Abra, I want to remove the entire node if the ClassScheduleID is the same, regardless of the rest

Comment: How do you determine which one to keep?  The one with `->Location->BusinessID == 1`.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Upon finding a duplicate entry, it would remove those that had a businessID == 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$count = 0;
foreach($arrayObj as $key => $value) {
    if ($value['ClassScheduleID'] == 2263) {
        $count++;
    }
    if ($count > 1){
        unset($arrayObj[$key]);
        $count--;
    }
}
```

**It works:** http://ideone.com/fork/zrdDtu

**Edit:** Modified to delete any duplicates:

```
foreach($arrayObj as $key => $value) {
    $count = 0;
    foreach($arrayObj as $nkey => $nvalue) {
        if ($value['ClassScheduleID'] == $nvalue['ClassScheduleID']) {
            $count++;
        }
        if ($count > 1){
            unset($arrayObj[$key]);
            $count--;
        }
    }
}

var_dump($arrayObj);
```

**See it here:** http://ideone.com/fork/85RCst

Comment: sorry, i guess i should have been more specific. i want it to remove ANY duplicate entries, the 2263 was just for demonstration

Answer (score 0):

```
function get_unique_array($array)
{
   $result = array_map("unserialize", array_unique(array_map("serialize", $array)));

   foreach ($result as $key => $value)
   {
      if ( is_array($value) )
      {
        $result[$key] = get_unique_array($value);
      }
   }

   return $result;
}
```

**Demo:** http://3v4l.org/WOTHi#v430

Comment: as with the previous example, it only removes complete duplicates in the array.